# How do I parse RFC 3339 datetimes with Java?

Tags: java, datetime, html, date-parsing, rfc3339

I'm trying to parse the date returned as a value from the HTML5 `datetime` input field. Try it in Opera to see an example. The date returned looks like this: `2011-05-03T11:58:01Z`.

I'd like to parse that into a Java Date or Calendar Object.

Ideally a solution should have the following things:

- No external libraries (jars)
- Handles all acceptable RFC 3339 formats
- A String should be able to be easily validated to see if it is a valid RFC 3339 date

Comment: Why the requirement for no external libraries?  Joda Time just *does* this.

Comment: I do like Joda Time. But this is for part of a framework and I don't want to add Joda Time as a dependency of the framework.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just found that google implemented Rfc3339 parser in Google HTTP Client Library

https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/blob/dev/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime.java

Tested. It works well to parse varies sub seconds time fragment.

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
            .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

@Test
public void test1e9Parse() {
    String timeStr = "2018-04-03T11:32:26.553955473Z";

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parseRfc3339(timeStr);
    long millis = dateTime.getValue();

    String result = formatter.format(new Date(millis).toInstant());

    assert result.equals("2018-04-03T11:32:26.553Z");
}

@Test
public void test1e3Parse() {
    String timeStr = "2018-04-03T11:32:26.553Z";

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parseRfc3339(timeStr);
    long millis = dateTime.getValue();

    String result = formatter.format(new Date(millis).toInstant());

    assert result.equals("2018-04-03T11:32:26.553Z");
}

@Test
public void testEpochSecondsParse() {

    String timeStr = "2018-04-03T11:32:26Z";

    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parseRfc3339(timeStr);
    long millis = dateTime.getValue();

    String result = formatter.format(new Date(millis).toInstant());

    assert result.equals("2018-04-03T11:32:26.000Z");
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using *java.time* classes (good). But there is no `DateTime` class in *java.time*. I am confused.

Comment: Im Sorry, forgot to write the import for DateTime class. It is belong to com.google.api.client.util package.

Answer (score 39):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2011-05-03T11:58:01Z" )
```

## ISO 8601

Actually, [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) is but a mere self-proclaimed “profile” of the actual standard, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

The RFC is different in that it purposely violates ISO 8601 to allow a negative offset of zero hours (`-00:00`) and gives that a semantic meaning of “offset unknown“. That semantic seems like a very bad idea to me. I advise sticking with the more sensible ISO 8601 rules. In ISO 8601, having no offset at all means the offset is unknown – an obvious meaning, whereas the RFC rule is abstruse.

The modern *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Your input string represents a moment in UTC. The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means UTC.

### `Instant` (not `Date`)

The modern class `Instant` represents a moment in UTC. This class replaces [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and uses a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2011-05-03T11:58:01Z" ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime` (not `Calendar`)

To see that same moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. This class `ZonedDateTime` replaces the [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

### Converting

I strongly recommend avoiding the legacy date-time classes when possible. But if you must inter-operate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you may convert back-and-forth. Call new methods added to the *old* classes.

`Instant` replaces `java.util.Date`.

```
java.util.Date myJUDate = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;  // From modern to legacy.
Instant instant = myJUDate.toInstant() ;                    // From legacy to modern.
```

`ZonedDateTime` replaces `GregorianCalendar`.

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar myGregCal = java.util.GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;  // From modern to legacy.
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;           // From legacy to modern.
```

If you have a `java.util.Calendar` that is actually a `GregorianCalendar`, cast.

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar myGregCal = ( java.util.GregorianCalendar ) myCal ;  // Cast to the concrete class.
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;           // From legacy to modern.
```

### Bulleted concerns

Regarding your Question’s specific issues…

- *No external libraries (jars)*

The *java.time* classes are built into Java 8, 9, 10, and later. An implementation is also included in later Android. For earlier Java and earlier Android, see the next section of this Answer.

- *Handles all acceptable RFC 3339 formats*

The various *java.time* classes handle every ISO 8601 format I know of. They even handle some formats that mysteriously disappeared from later editions of the standard.

For other formats, see the `parse` and `toString` methods of the various classes such as `LocalDate`, `OffsetDateTime`, and so on. Also, search Stack Overflow as there are *many* examples and discussions on this topic.

- *A String should be able to be easily validated to see if it is a valid RFC 3339 date*

To validate input strings, trap for [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

```
try {
    Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2011-05-03T11:58:01Z" ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    … handle invalid input
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, `Instant` keeps failing on dates with timezone, `2019-11-30T10:30:00+02:00` or `2019-10-12T07:20:50.52+00:00`, both with and without milliseconds. It fails with errors like `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-11-30T10:30:00+02:00' could not be parsed at index 19`, or same on `index 23`.
Therefore I can't use it in production, it does not actually support RFC-3339.

Comment: @DmitriyPopov `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-11-30T10:30:00+02:00" )` and `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-10-12T07:20:50.52+00:00" )`. All of the *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default for parsing/generating text. You just need to choose the appropriate *java.time* class for the semantics of your text.

Comment: Saying one needs to choose the appropriate `java.time` class for the semantics of the text is a bit disingenuous. The semantics is all valid RFC3339 and you seem to be saying I need to first parse it to figure out what class to use to parse it?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Use the class appropriate to each kind of value. For a value in UTC, use `Instant`. For a value with an offset, use `OffsetDateTime`. For a value with a time zone, use `ZonedDateTime`. For a value lacking any offset or time zone, use `LocalDateTime`. It’s really not that complicated. How is that “disingenuous”?

Comment: It is disingenuous because finding out whether a value is UTC or offset is part of the parsing. If I have a protocol with a field saying "RFC3339 timestamp", then all valid RFC3339 values must be accepted when decoding it. Alas, named time zones are not valid RFC3339.

Answer (score 16):

So, in principle this would be done using different [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns.

Here a list of patterns for the [individual declarations in RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6):

- date-fullyear:  `yyyy`
- date-month:     `MM`
- date-mday:      `dd`
- time-hour:      `HH`
- time -minute:   `mm`
- time-second:    `ss`
- time-secfrac:   `.SSS`  (`S` means millisecond, though - it is not clear what would happen if there are more or less than 3 digits of these.)
- time-numoffset: (like `+02:00` seems to be not supported - instead it supports the formats `+0200`, `GMT+02:00` and some named time zones using `z` and `Z`.)
- time-offset:    `'Z'`   (not supporting other time zones) - you should use `format.setTimezone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))` before using this.)
- partial-time:   `HH:mm:ss` or `HH:mm:ss.SSS`.
- full-time:      `HH:mm:ss'Z'` or `HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`.
- full-date:      `yyyy-MM-dd`
- date-time:      `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` or `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

As we can see, this seems not to be able to parse everything. Maybe it would be a better idea to implement an `RFC3339DateFormat` from scratch (using regular expressions, for simplicity, or parsing by hand, for efficiency).

Comment: Shouldn't `date-fullyear` be `yyyy`?

Comment: Looks like you are right here – EEEE is for "day of week". I'm not sure where I got this from, maybe from another library which made something different for `y`?

Comment: With Java 7+ SimpleDateFormat adds the [X timezone format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) a superset of Z format accepting +/- two-digit or four-digit with optional colon (but minutes are ignored)

Comment: SimpleDateFormat chokes on fractions beyond millis.

Comment: @Thomas While I'm using Java 8, I've never had the need of parsing dates with it (it was always already done in the libraries I've been using for HTTP and/or Json mapping). Feel free to add your own answer, I would upvote it. (It looks like [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) includes this functionality.)

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I posted [an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49639543/642706) showing the modern approach using *java.time* classes built into Java 8, 9, 10, and later. The legacy date-time classes really are a wretched mess of poor design (however well-intentioned) that should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

With the format you have e.g. 2011-05-03T11:58:01Z, below code will do. However, I recently tryout html5 datetime in Chrome and Opera, it give me 2011-05-03T11:58Z --> do not have the ss part which cannot be handled by code below.

```
new Timestamp(javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(date).toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the most elegant way, but certainly working one I recently made:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss");
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(dateInString.replace("Z", "").replace("T", "-")));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```java
DateTimeFormatter RFC_3339_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "Z")
            .optionalEnd()
            .toFormatter();
```

Example:

```java
String dateTimeString = "2007-05-01T15:43:26.3452+07:00";
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.from(RFC_3339_DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.parse(dateTimeString));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I have a tool which still must support Java 8 and I just discovered that the offset pattern "+HH:MM" was not standard in JDK8.
In earlier JDK versions, however, (I tried on Java 17) just calling `Instant.parse(string)` will be enough to support both offset options out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

Though, The question is very old, but it may help one who wants it Kotlin version of this answer. By using this file, anyone can convert a Rfc3339 date to any date-format. Here I take a empty file name **`DateUtil`** and create a function called **`getDateString()`** which has 3 arguments.

```
1st argument : Your input date
2nd argument : Your input date pattern
3rd argument : Your wanted date pattern
```

`DateUtil.kt`

```
object DatePattern {
    const val DAY_MONTH_YEAR = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    const val RFC3339 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
}

fun getDateString(date: String, inputDatePattern: String, outputDatePattern: String): String {
    return try {
        val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat(inputDatePattern, getDefault())
        val outputFormat = SimpleDateFormat(outputDatePattern, getDefault())

        outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(date))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        ""
    }
}
```

And now use this method in your activity/fuction/dataSourse Mapper to get Date in String format like this

```
getDate("2022-01-18T14:41:52Z", RFC3339, DAY_MONTH_YEAR)
```

and output will be like this

```
18-01-2022
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, as an alternative, you could use ITU[1] which is hand-written to deal with exactly RFC-3339 parsing and also lets you easily deal with leap seconds. The library is dependency-free and only weighs in at 18 kB.

Full disclosure: I'm the author

```java
try 
{
    final OffsetDateTime dateTime = ITU.parseDateTime(dateTimeStr);
}
catch (LeapSecondException exc) 
{
  // The following helper methods are available let you decide how to progress
  //int exc.getSecondsInMinute()
  //OffsetDateTime exc.getNearestDateTime()
  //boolean exc.isVerifiedValidLeapYearMonth()
}
```

[1] - https://github.com/ethlo/itu

Answer (score -1):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parse(datetimeInFRC3339format)
```