# How to calculate difference between now and a RFC3339 timestamp in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, datetime, rfc3339

I am importing some sensor-data in my app over a server with JSON objects. They contain the value and time of the last measurement.

The time is in **RFC3339** format send as a string, e.g. `2020-06-19T15:32:25.528Z`.

Now, instead of displaying the last measurement´s time, I want to show the **time difference** between *now* and the *measurement*.

Searching I found neither a good solution to parse a RFC3339 timestamp string to an editable format, nor a way to calculate the difference to now.
The only thing I saw is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038136/how-do-i-parse-rfc-3339-datetimes-with-java) article, but couldn´t manage to import the *datetime*-class in my app.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Searching I found neither a good solution to parse a RFC3339 timestamp
> string to an editable format, nor a way to calculate the difference to
> now.

### Use [java.time.Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html)

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given date-time
        LocalDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime
                .parse("2020-06-19T15:32:25.528Z",
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz").withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()))
                .toLocalDateTime();

        // Get the duration between the given date-time and now
        Duration duration = Duration.between(ldt, LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));

        // Get hours, minutes, seconds from the Duration object
        System.out.printf("%d hours %d minutes %d seconds%n", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3 hours 3 minutes 43 seconds
```

**[Update]**

Note that `Duration#toXXXXXPart()` e.g. `Duration#toHoursPart()` was introduced with Java-9. If you are using Java-8, you can use the calculation shown below:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given date-time
        LocalDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime
                .parse("2020-06-19T15:32:25.528Z",
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz").withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()))
                .toLocalDateTime();

        // Get the duration between the given date-time and now
        Duration duration = Duration.between(ldt, LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));

        // Get hours, minutes, seconds from the Duration object
        System.out.printf("%d hours %d minutes %d seconds%n", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());

        // For Java-8
        long hours = duration.toHours();
        int minutes = (int) ((duration.getSeconds() % (60 * 60)) / 60);
        int seconds = (int) (duration.getSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.printf("%d hours %d minutes %d seconds%n", hours, minutes, seconds);
    }
}
```

**[Another Update]** Courtesy [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475267/how-to-calculate-difference-between-now-and-a-rfc3339-timestamp-in-android-studi/62475639#comment110505329_62475639)

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given date-time
        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2020-06-19T15:32:25.528Z");

        // Get the duration between the given date-time and now
        Duration duration = Duration.between(instant, Instant.now());

        // Get hours, minutes, seconds from the Duration object
        System.out.printf("%d hours %d minutes %d seconds%n", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                duration.toSecondsPart());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea.
There is only one problem: trying to implement your suggestion, Android Studio told me that there are **no** to...Part()-methods and even no toSeconds()-method.
Although I used the same imports as you did and Oracle knows this methods.
**Any idea why?**

Comment: @Anonymix - I've posted an update. I hope, it helps. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: (1) `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use since it ignores the offset in the source string, which is critical to know for a correct result. I recommend `Instant`. (2) You don’t need to specify a formatter. Each of `Instant.parse()` and the one-arg `OffsetDateTime.parse()` will parse the RFC-3339 string without any explicit formatter.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for the valuable suggestion as always. I've incorporated it in the answer as an update.